# Создание целого объекта из нескольких тайлов в TileMap

Tags: unity3d, tilemap

Подскажите, есть ли возможность отрисовывать "картинку" из тайлов в скрипте?
Вот пример, у меня есть дерево из двух тайлов, и чтобы нарисовать это дерево я использовал TileBase и в скрипте через цикл проверял для каждого тайла этого дерева доступность на карте, чтобы оно не накладывалось на что-нибудь еще, также пришлось изворачиваться с расположением второго куска дерева путем изменения его местоположения, чтобы оно находилось рядом с первым куском, а не лежало где-то еще. Тут всего два тайла, окей, извернулся, но как быть с, допустим, большим домом на тайлов 30? Могу я как-то сделать префаб из тайлов и рисовать этот префаб где мне нужно? Или есть еще какой-нибудь выход?
Вот мой "изверт":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]